# Number of Delannoy paths that never go below the line $y = x$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

How would I go about calculating $D(a,b)$ the number of such paths 
for some a,b.
 Say $a,b<=4$ and then express $D(a,b)$ in terms of another delannoy number?

I have calculated $D(a,b)$ using a recurrence relation without any restrictions but dont know what to do with the $y=x$ line.

Answer (score 0):

These numbers are given by the Schröder triangle, [OEIS A$106579$](http://oeis.org/A106579), with indexing offset by $1$: $T(n,k)$ in that entry is the number of Delannoy paths from $\langle 0,0\rangle$ to $\langle n-1,k-1\rangle$ that do not drop below the diagonal. The most useful link given seems to be the one to E. Pergola and R. A. Sulanke, [*Schröder triangles, paths, and parallelogram polyominoes*](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/PergolaSulanke/PergolaSulanke.html), J.
Integer Seq., Article $98.1.7.$, $\mathbf{1}$ ($1998$). That paper uses the notation $R(m,n)$ for the number of Delannoy paths from $\langle 0,0\rangle$ to $\langle m,n\rangle$ that do not drop below the diagonal.

In [Section $2$](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/PergolaSulanke/node2.html) the authors give the recurrences

$$R(m,n)=R(m,n-1)+2\sum_{j\ge 1}R(m-j,n-1)\;,$$

with initial conditions $R(0,0)=1$, and $R(m,n)=0$ if $m<0$ or $n<m$, and, more usefully,

$$R(m,n)=R(m,n-1)+R(m-1,n-1)+R(m-1,n)$$

with the same initial conditions. In [Section $6.1$](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/PergolaSulanke/node6.html) they derive the formula

$$R(m,n)=\frac{n-m+1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{n+1}{m-k}\binom{n+k}k\;.$$